# Sharepoint Read only Not supported in chrome

Tags: access, chrome, read

I have a SP 2013 document library with unique permissions. Condition is Read only user can just view the document but not download and not open in browser.
This works fine with IE. However when opened with **chrome documents open in browser**. I have already made Library Settings-Advanced settings-Open in client application. Is there a work around to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The permission is called View Only and allows the person to view the file in the browser and not download it. The permission called Read allows the user to view and download the document.

Other than those 2 options I do not know what you are trying to achieve. The only way to prevent downloading is VIEW ONLY and it requires Office web application and viewing in the browser. You cannot have one without the other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently the permission setting is View only. When the file is opened in IE it directs to a page saying you don't have access and request for access comes. But in Chrome, the file gets opened in the browser and user is unable to request for contribute access to download

Comment: View only ALLOWS the file to be opened in the browser, so it looks like Chrome is having the correct behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Susan. My requirement is , user shld be able to see the files in document library. Onclick of the document, incase if he has read only he must be able to raise an access request to grant access for download. Is there a way i can achieve this. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't such automatism. Only on access denied there is a chance to submit a request to an email address.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/disable-excel-web-access.My issue is same as this. Did anyone get a fix?
http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=133 - I tried this along with IIS reset still no luck. please assist