# Download excel instead of open from server

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, internet-explorer

I have users that have read only access to some excel files in SharePoint. When they try to open it in IE, it opens from the server in read only mode. I need them to be able to download the files and edit a local copy on their machine.

I currently have SharePoint Online and it is a modern document library. I have a link on a SitePage that they click to access it.

Is there a way to force IE to download a copy rather than open from server?

Answer (score 0):

To quote [this article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/disable-excel-web-access):

> Have you checked this documentation: [Configure the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents (Office Web Apps)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx)
>
> You can either disable the Excel Services Application for all site
>   collection in the central administration (Service Applications under
>   APplication Managemend) , or you can disable the Web Access via
>   Feature/Powershell explained in the above article.